# setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps does not map Caps Lock to Escape inside Debian VM running in Oracle VirtualBox on macOS

Tags: debian, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-machine, keyboard-layout

I am using Xfce 4.12 on Debian 10 running inside Oracle VirtualBox 6.1 running on macOS Catalina.

All my key mappings are set to default on macOS. (System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys > Restore Defaults > Ok.)

#### caps to escape works fine

In the Debian VM, I run:

```
$ setxkbmap -option
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us

$ setxkbmap -option caps:escape
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    caps:escape
```

Now caps lock behaves like escape in the Debian VM and caps lock behave like caps lock on the macOS system. This is working as expected.

Here is `xev` output when I press caps lock after `setxkbmap -option`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 128721870, (-31,207), root:(560,530),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 128721874, (-31,207), root:(560,530),
    state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here is `xev` output when I press caps lock after `setxkbmap -option caps:escape`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 128844487, (163,5), root:(754,328),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 128844489, (163,5), root:(754,328),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

#### caps to control does not work fine

In the Debian VM, I run:

```
$ setxkbmap -option
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us

$ setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    ctrl:nocaps
```

Now Caps Lock does not behave like Ctrl modifier inside the Debian VM.

Here is `xev` output when I press caps lock after `setxkbmap -option`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 129089370, (163,1), root:(754,324),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 129089373, (163,1), root:(754,324),
    state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here is `xev` output when I press caps lock after `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 129117033, (163,5), root:(754,328),
    state 0x2, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 129117037, (163,5), root:(754,328),
    state 0x6, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What went wrong?

#### more xev output on this issue.

If you follow the comment section below, you will find that I have established so far that after running `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`, <kbd>caps lock</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> types the letter `c` but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> behaves correctly (example: cancels the current command in bash).

Here is the xev output for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176921083, (165,3), root:(756,326),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176921220, (165,3), root:(756,326),
    state 0x4, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176921334, (165,3), root:(756,326),
    state 0x4, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176921336, (165,3), root:(756,326),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Here is the output for `caps lock`+`c`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176819139, (165,5), root:(756,328),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176819141, (165,5), root:(756,328),
    state 0x4, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176819251, (165,5), root:(756,328),
    state 0x0, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x3ac, subw 0x0, time 176819371, (165,5), root:(756,328),
    state 0x0, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The issue here seems to be is that the original <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> sends the proper key events in correct sequence:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> press
- <kbd>c</kbd> press
- <kbd>c</kbd> release
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> release)

But the <kbd>caps lock</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> combination sends the key events in incorrect sequence:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> press
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> release
- <kbd>c</kbd> press
- <kbd>c</kbd> release

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `xev` say when you press Caps Lock?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Added `xev` outputs to the question.

Comment: Hmm, according to `xev` Control key is sent as it should be. Why do you think that *still behaves like Caps Lock*?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk You are right. It does not behave like Caps Lock anymore. However, I do not get the Control key modifier behavior either. For example, in the Bash shell I type `ls` followed immediately by `ctrl`+`c` and instead of seeing `^C` appearing on the terminal and the command being cancelled (and the shell prompt reappearing), I see only the letter `c` appearing thus making the command `lsc`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. `You are right. It does not behave like
Caps Lock anymore. It does not behave like Caps Lock anymore` - this
is what you want, right? `However, I do not get the Control key
modifier behavior either` - *either*?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Sorry, I am not proficient at English. Let me rephrase again. After running `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`, Caps Lock does not behave like Caps Lock anymore. This is good. But it does not behave like Control which is bad. After `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`, if I type `Caps Lock` + `c`, I get only `c` typed. I don't get the `ctrl` + `c` behavior.

Comment: And does Control-c (real Control, not Caps Lock) work correctly?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes, `ctrl`+`c` works correctly. But `caps lock`+`c` does not. If I type `ctrl`+`c` on the Bash prompt in a terminal, `^C` appears at the current shell prompt and then a new shell prompt appears below it. If I type `caps lock`+`c`, only the letter `c` appears.

Comment: Hmm, I have never seen such problem. Can you try `setxkbmap -option && setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I have added more `xev` output to the question. It gives a clue. The `caps lock` key fires both the press and release events immediately even if I hold it down. So when I press the `c` key, the release event of `ctrl` from the `caps lock` key is already over, so it does not act like a modifier key.

Comment: Maybe it's hardware issue? What keyboard do you have?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Same issue with `setxkbmap -option && setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps`. Inside the VM, pressing and holding the `caps lock` key fires both the press and release events for `ctrl` immediately even if I've not released `caps lock` yet. I am using a MacBook Pro host system with its regular keyboard. It works fine. If I map `Caps Lock` to `Ctrl` on the host macOS system, it works correctly. If I leave `Caps Lock` as `Caps Lock` on the host macOS and map it to `ctrl` in the Debian VM, I have this issue inside the VM.

Comment: Can you try another window manager, i3 for example?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Maybe this is an issue regarding how Oracle VirtualBox emulates `caps lock` key press. Even without any key mappings (that is `setxkbmap -option`), `xev` shows that both press and release events of caps lock have been fired even before I have released the `caps lock` key. It does not wait for me to release the `caps lock` key and fires its release event too early.

Comment: What's your `Host Key Combination` set to (File->Preferences->Input->Virtual Machine->Host Key Combination)?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Same issue with `i3` window manager too. Caps Lock fires the `ctrl` press and release events immediately. The Host Key Combination is `Right ⌘`.

Comment: I have used Virtual Box for years I have never had such problems and
out of curiosity I tried Debian 10 with Xfce 4.12 in VirtualBox
Version 6.1.10 r138449 on Slackware x64 -current and Control works as
expected after doing `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` in Bash in
xfce4-terminal 0.8.7.4.

Comment: I mean, Caps Lock acts as Control as expected.